# Generate java code from xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, code-generation

I have a few XML files that our backed by XSD files we use for our application. In order to unit test and load test data in an easy manner I'm looking for a method that will parse the XML file and generate a factory class for each node in the XML file.

For instance say I have an xml file:

```
<xml>
    <case>
        <identifier>123</identifier>
    </case>
    <case>
        <identifier>456</identifier>
    </case>
</xml>
```

I would like to generate the class

```
public class CaseBuilderFactory {

    public void saveCase123() {
       service.saveCase(XML_RESOURCE_FILE, 123);
    }

    public Case getCase123() {
        service.getCase(123);
    }

}
```

We are a java project, we use maven as a build tool and it would be preferred if it can be integrated into our build process. I'm not sure if this is even possible, the XML files don't change often so maybe it is easier to just write a few scripts to generate the code that we will run once or twice and commit the code directly to our repository

Comment: As posed, all the trouble is hiding in the place you did not describe:  "code to save/generate case 123".    What would the code generator use as information telling it what to generate?  You "XML" specification is completely silent on the topic.  What *is* case123?

Comment: The method bodies are quite generic, they would call the same business service method and with more or less the same input parameters with the exception of the identifier.

Comment: I updated the code snippets with an example but what I need there is quite simple. The code to persist and get the objects already exists as long as I can feed in the XML resource file and the identifier. What I need is a factory method that allows a developer to easily persist a case and get a case to unit test existing services that require a case to be saved

Comment: So why can't you just use your "generated class" as a text template and plug in "123"?  That would be trivial to do.  I'm sure it isn't this easy and that's why I think you haven't told us what you really need to do.